# Turn iframe Elements Into Text Data? - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, hta

With an iframe element,

```
<iframe id="">
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
<body>
<element attribute=""></element>
<etc... />
</body>
</html>
</iframe>
```

how would I get all the child elements of the iframe, not including the iframe element itself, copy the elements as text, and append that text to a textarea element, with an id, all compatible with:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">
```

...using JavaScript.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is the iframe hosted on the same domain as the parent page?

Comment: Did you try using document.queryselector("iframeid); this will give you all the child elements. then you can massage on the data.

Comment: Give a name to the iframe, and get `document.frames['frame_name'].document.documentElement.outerHTML`, that's text which you can add to a textarea.

Comment: ... and don't forget to add `application="true"` attribute to the iframe element, without it you can't access the iframe document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not talking about the communication between methods from different frames it doesn't matter where the iframe is hosted. Without regarding that concept, if you want to access some DOM Element, `contentWindow` of the `HTMLIFrame​Element​` can be used. Even manipulating an element with this method is allowed in client-side. More details are explained in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/contentWindow)

> The contentWindow property returns the Window object of an  element. You can use this Window object to access the iframe's document and its internal DOM. This attribute is read-only, but its properties can be manipulated like the global Window object.

#### An example

Consider you have an iframe and its Shadow DOM Tree and you want to access a `span` element declared with `foo` id.

```
// HTMLIFrame​Element 
let someIframe = document.getElementBy("idOfIframe");

// Global Object of the Iframe
let frameWindow = someIframe.contentWindow;

// Dom Tree of the Target Window
let domTreeofFrame = frameWindow.document;

let textSpan = domTreeofFrame.getElementById("foo");
```